# new bmatrix environment

Tags: environments

I need to define a new environment which is exactly like

```
\begin{bmatrix*}[cc]\end{bmatrix*}
```

environment but I want to replace `[cc]` with `{cc}` in the new environment. How can I do that?

The reason I need this is that I have a very large file where I used the `array` environment for typesetting matrices. I want to use the `bmatrix*` environment which is from the `mathtool` package, because it has nicer typesetting; however it uses `[cc]` instead of `{cc}`.

Comment: Could you please add some background information on why you want to define such a new environment and what yourput you would expect?

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: the `[` in `[cc]` do not make the `[` in the output, they are marking an optional argument, like `[a4paper]` are you looking for `\begin{matrix}` ? the `b` in `bmatrix` is for _brackets_ ie [...] in the output.

Comment: I guess \begin{bmatrix*} is different from \begin{bmatrix}

Comment: `bmatrix*` is a non standard environment from a package that you have not mentioned, but like `bmatrix`  it uses brackets. You want `matrix` or `matrix*`

Comment: I want matrix*. I guess it uses square brackets. It is from mathtools package

Comment: `bmatrix*` is different from matrix, it has the optional argument that you used, although as the default alignment os centre anyway  the outcome is the same in this case.

Comment: I have different alignment in my document. not all of them are centered. [cc] was just an example. I should have used [rr]

Comment: @Yasi I know it comes from `mathtools` but _you_ should have put that in  the question (preferably with a test document) rather than rely on people to guess. So is "use `matrix*`" the answer that you need?

Comment: I can't work it out: Is it possible you're after `Bmatrix` - this'll give you matrices with braces (or `Bmatrix*` if you prefer)

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: this seems to me task for your LaTeX editor function "find-repalce"... with run for all combination of column specifiers you can convert your arrays to  `matrix`

Answer (score 1):

the `bmatrix*` environment is from `mathtools` the `b` denotes *brackets* and puts [..] in the output.

You are apparently looking for `matrix*` which uses no delimiters, or `Bmatrix*` which uses {...}

Your description of the question as replacing `[cc]` by `{cc}` made the question hard to answer as the `[` in `[cc]` is denoting an optional argument, unrelated to the use of brackets in the output, but this was clarified in comments.

Comment: Thanks. Then, what is the answer to the clarified question?

Comment: @Yasi ???  _this_ is the answer to the clarified question, isn't it? (the original question, as still in your question post,  has no answer as you did not say what output you wanted, just that you wanted to replace the legal syntax `[cc]` by the syntax error `{cc}` so I (and I think others) had no idea what you actually wanted to achieve)